# Remove Separators focus from ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listviewitem

I just wrote some ListViewItem Style that contains Separator in ContentTemplate. a problem is when I click item, Separator have focus with ContentPresenter. but I want remove Separators focus and only ContentPresenter have focus.

what should I do?

```
<Style x:Key="AltItemBackground" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Separator x:Name="Separator"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E6E6E6"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: So the problem is that the blue selection box contains the separator as well? I'm not sure I understand what's the problem..

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi yes, right. sorry i'm not a native speaker and not good at english.

Comment: Added an answer, please check if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default `ControlTemplate` of a `ListViewItem` and modifying it a bit I created this application, maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewItemSeparator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Separator x:Name="Separator" />
                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" 
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" 
                                    Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" 
                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" 
                                                  ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" 
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#1F26A0DA" />
                                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#A826A0DA" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3DDADADA" />
                                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFDADADA" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3D26A0DA" />
                                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A0DA" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter TargetName="Separator" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />    

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E6E6E6"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsControl.AlternationCount="2">
            <system:String>First item</system:String>
            <system:String>Second item</system:String>
            <system:String>Third item</system:String>
            <system:String>Fourth item</system:String>
            <system:String>Fifth item</system:String>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Unselected state:

[image: unselected]

Selected state:

[image: selected]